# Dynamic Menu Data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a side navigation menu in the type of a treeview format.The issue I am facing is that the side navigation bar should accommodate data from the database. I have written the following code.

```
private void GetMenuData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
    string sql = "select SiteName from SiteMaster";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(table);
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    foreach (DataRowView row in view)
    {
     sites.InnerHtml= Server.HtmlDecode("<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-circle-o text-warning'></i>" + row["SiteName"].ToString() + "</a></li>");
    }
}
```

The SiteMaster table contains list of SiteName. The problem here is that only the last SiteName is being displayed in the side menu. I Want all the rows under the SiteName column to be displayed.

*Sites is the id given for `<ul>`*

Comment: You need to format your code so it's readable!

Comment: I am so sorry, I just copy pasted from VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like

```
sites.InnerHtml += Server.HtmlDecode ...
```

instead of

```
sites.InnerHtml = Server.HtmlDecode ...
```